# Convert list of strings to date

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have been working on a function that will take three strings in a list, one for the year, one for the month, and one for the day, and have it return a date that represents that day.

```
from datetime import datetime 

def make_a_date(values):
    date1 = ""
    for value in values:
        date1 += value
    date2 = datetime.datetime(int(date1)).date()
    return date2

print(make_a_date(["2022", "11", "8"]))
```

The above code however gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in make_a_date
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime.strptime`

```
def make_a_date(values):
    date1 = "-".join(values)
    # print(date1)
    date2 = datetime.strptime(date1, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    return date2

print(make_a_date(["2022", "11", "8"]))
```

Output:

```
2022-11-08
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix your import a bit and use more builtin python functions to achieve this result

```
from datetime import date

def make_a_date(values):
    date2 = date(*map(int,values))
    return date2

print(make_a_date(["2022", "11", "8"]))
```

or one liner if you don't want a function

```
from datetime import date 


print(date(*map(int, ["2022", "11", "8"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_a_date(values):
    date2 = datetime(year = values[0], month = values[1], day = values[2])
    return date2

print(make_a_date([2022, 11, 8]))
```